# Terraform Custom Provider - Data Source Schema

Tags: go, sdk, terraform, schema, terraform-provider

I am working on creating a custom terraform provider by using terraform sdk. I am trying to read data from the existing API GET call. I am finding it difficult to map the JSON response from an API to terraform schema. This is my data source schema:

```golang
func dataSourceProjects() *schema.Resource {
  return &schema.Resource{
    ReadContext: dataSourceProjectsRead,
    Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
      "members": &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        Elem:     &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
        Computed: true,
      },
      "owners": &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        Elem:     &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
        Computed: true,
      },
    },
  }
}
```

This is the API JSON response:

```json
{
  "members": [
    "test12",
    "test8800",
    "test0032",
    "test1234"
  ],
  "owners": [
    "test000",
    "test111",
    "test12",
    "test1234"
  ]
}
```

This is my Data source read function

```golang
func dataSourceProjectsRead(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {

  client := &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}

  // Warning or errors can be collected in a slice type
  var diags diag.Diagnostics

  req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("%s/test/team", "https://myurl/v1"), nil)
  req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer xxxxx")
  if err != nil {
    return diag.FromErr(err)
  }

  r, err := client.Do(req)
  if err != nil {
    return diag.FromErr(err)
  }
  defer r.Body.Close()
  members := make([]string, 0)
  err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&members)
  if err != nil {
    return diag.FromErr(err)
  }

  if err := d.Set("members", members); err != nil {
    return diag.FromErr(err)
  }

  // always run
  d.SetId(strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10))

  return diags
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> **Error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []string**

Comment: try by passing `make(map[string]interface{})` into `Decode` and then check what you are getting then update the `members` structure accordingly if this not work then directly try with interface{}

Comment: please can you share [`MWE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible

Comment: I have added two functions "dataSourceProjects" and "dataSourceProjectsRead" which are relevant to terraform sdk work. This is the document I followed https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-setup and here is the repository https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-hashicups/tree/implement-read

Comment: The only difference is I am consuming my already existing api and not the one mentioned in this document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**server.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    s := `
    {
      "members": [
        "test12",
        "test8800",
        "test0032",
        "test1234"
      ],
      "owners": [
        "test000",
        "test111",
        "test12",
        "test1234"
      ]
    }
    `

    http.HandleFunc("/projects", func(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
      log.Println("Getting Projects")
      w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
      w.Write([]byte(s))
    })

    log.Println("Listening...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

**data_source_projects.go**

```golang
package hashicups

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/diag"
    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema"
)

func dataSourceProjects() *schema.Resource {
  return &schema.Resource{
    ReadContext: dataSourceProjectsRead,
    Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
      "members": &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        Elem:     &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
        Computed: true,
      },
      "owners": &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        Elem:     &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
        Computed: true,
      },
    },
  }
}

func dataSourceProjectsRead(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {
    client := &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}

    // Warning or errors can be collected in a slice type
    var diags diag.Diagnostics

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("%s/projects", "http://localhost:8000"), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return diag.FromErr(err)
    }

    r, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return diag.FromErr(err)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    var projects map[string]interface{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&projects)
    if err != nil {
        return diag.FromErr(err)
    }

    if err := d.Set("members", projects["members"]); err != nil {
        return diag.FromErr(err)
    }

    if err := d.Set("owners", projects["owners"]); err != nil {
        return diag.FromErr(err)
    }

    // always run
    d.SetId(strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10))

    return diags
}
```

**Output:**

```
Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes


Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

project = {
  "id" = "1651575329"
  "members" = tolist([
    "test12",
    "test8800",
    "test0032",
    "test1234",
  ])
  "owners" = tolist([
    "test000",
    "test111",
    "test12",
    "test1234",
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Matt and the error code mentioned, you're trying to unmarshal your body to an improper struct.

Basically, you don't have an array in the Body, you have an object with fields that have an array of strings.

Your way of unmarshalling would work for bodies like

```json
["test12", "test23", "test34"]
```

Try to decode it as below, so use a struct with explicit mapping.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Schema struct {
    Members []string `json:"members"`
    Owners  []string `json:"owners"`
}

var jsonBody = `{
  "members": [
    "test12",
    "test8800",
    "test0032",
    "test1234"
  ],
  "owners": [
    "test000",
    "test111",
    "test12",
    "test1234"
  ]
}`

func main() {
    var s Schema
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonBody), &s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }

}
```